# SQL iterative joining within while loop

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, left-join, temp-tables

I know that it's not best practice to apply a `while` loop within SQL code, but I can't really imagine a way around it.

I have an ever-growing set of historical tables that I want to summarize, and join, using a common ID. All of these historical tables have matching structure.

The table names contain the month and year; I iterate through all tables found between two periods - determined using the fixed timestamp `@StartDate`, and the timestamp `@EndDate` via `GETDATE()`.

The `while` loop is intended to continually append additional columns from each historic file. There is one month per iteration, and each column contains the pertaining month's summary.

The problem is, every `left join` seems to erase what was there in the previous iteration. I use a conditional statement to determine if the temp table exists, and build it using a `select ... into` statement if it doesn't, and an `insert into` statement if it does.

The following is what I have:

```
while @MonthCount > 0
    begin
        select @Month = DateSuffix from @DateTable where Row = @MonthCount
        select @Table = table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like concat('USA_RETHHDs_%', @Month)
        if @Table is not null
            begin
                if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#RETHHDS', 'U') is not null
                    drop table #RETHHDS
                create table #RETHHDS
                    (BUC_CD varchar(12),
                    RET_BKD_HH_COUNT int)
                select @Table = concat('dbo.', @Table)
            set @sql =
                'insert into #RETHHDS 
                select BUC_CD, count(distinct SK_HH_ID) as RET_BKD_HH_COUNT from ' + @Table +
                ' group by BUC_CD'
            execute SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
            if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#HISTORICAL_TABLE', 'U') is null
                begin
                    select #USA_BRANCHCATALOGUE.TR, #USA_BRANCHCATALOGUE.NAME, #RETHHDS.RET_BKD_HH_COUNT into #HISTORICAL_TABLE
                    from #USA_BRANCHCATALOGUE
                    left join #RETHHDS
                    on #USA_BRANCHCATALOGUE.TR = #RETHHDS.BUC_CD
                end
            else
                begin
                    insert into #HISTORICAL_TABLE
                    select #USA_BRANCHCATALOGUE.TR, #USA_BRANCHCATALOGUE.NAME, #RETHHDS.RET_BKD_HH_COUNT
                    from #USA_BRANCHCATALOGUE
                    left join #RETHHDS
                    on #USA_BRANCHCATALOGUE.TR = #RETHHDS.BUC_CD
                end
            select * from #HISTORICAL_TABLE
        end 
    select @MonthCount = @MonthCount - 1
end
```

As I loop through, the `#HISTORICAL_TABLE` does not grow with additional rightmost columns. Instead, it remains with columns `TR`, `NAME`, and `RET_BKD_HH_COUNT`.

Bonus points if there's an easy way to append the corresponding month to the `RET_BKD_HH_COUNT` field. However, when I do the following,

```
set @sql =
'create table #RETHHDS
(BUC_CD varchar(12),
RET_BKD_HH_COUNT_' + @Month + ' int)'
execute SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
```

I receive the following message:

`Invalid object name '#RETHHDS'.`

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do here (and I'm not sure I do), I think you'd have much better luck unioning all the tables together and then pivoting the results out (if you need them going out to the right) rather than trying to add an arbitrary number of columns, dynamically, for as many historical tables as you query.

Comment: I am going to assume you are not on a version that supports partitioning.... because preventing X number of historical tables is exactly what partitioning is for. Either use a union view like Xedni suggested or at the very least stop dropping the temp table inside the loop.

Comment: Yikes why on earth would you have designed a table structure like that?

Comment: @HLGEM - I'm pretty new to SQL. Simply put, I need one month summaries within each column, going back n number of months. I'm going to try to apply Xedni's suggestion, and report back.

Comment: @TheMadDBA - the #RETHHDS needs to be dropped within every loop in order to refresh with the pertaining month. I'm not dropping the temp table that the join is applied to - #HISTORICAL_TABLE

Comment: I don't see any ALTER TABLE statement in your code, so how is it you're expecting it to grow horizontally (add new columns)?

Comment: Still no reason to drop and recreate it every time. If your table structure was close to sane it would be a simple query with a pivot for the months.

Comment: @TabAlleman - That's a good point - show's my lack of knowledge with SQL! However, this approach was complicated by the fact that each column must be unique, so appending the month to the appended column name made the most sense. However, this required dynamic SQL,  and resulted in error messages stating the column could not be found (on the `insert into` line) - `set @sql = 'alter table #HISTORICAL_TABLE add ' + @Month + ' int
insert into #HISTORICAL_TABLE (' + @Month + ')
select #RETHHDS.RET_BKD_HH_COUNT`